# TextView drawable posts (Android)

Tags: android, textview, drawable, shapes, message

I need to know how to create a drawable comic style for a TextView. I do not need a simple border radius, but a form like this: http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/iOS-7-Messages-timestamps.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 9 patch background would probably work for that.  See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html